# Basic MySQL problem

Tags: mysql, sql

Why doesn't `SELECT * FROM users_meta where user = 1 and key = tagline` work?

It works without the `key = tagline`. But I need that!

`users_meta` is a table with these fields:
id, key, value, user.

I'm trying get the value from a row with `key = tagline` and `user = 1`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is because key is a MySQL keyword. If it is also a column name in your table, then you need to surround it in backticks. Like:

```
`key` = 'tagline'
```

Answer (score 7):

Syntax. Backticks around reserved words used as identifiers, single quotes around string literals.

```
SELECT * FROM users_meta WHERE user = 1 AND `key` = 'tagline'
```